# Upload files PHP Puts into post request

Tags: php, forms, image, post, multipartform-data

**Upload files PHP Puts into post request**

I am trying to insert a image into a MySQL database from a HTML Form with `enctype='multipart/form-data'` instead of being saved to `$_FILES` it is being saved to `$_POST` Array.

We have no clue how this is currently happening. We inserted images with the exact same code before but now when we try the exact same code in this file it doesnt work we don't know why.

If someone can help us with this we would highly appreciate it.

****First our HTML Code:****

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype='multipart/form-data'>
                    <div class="border-t flex justify-center mt-6 pt-3">
                        <div class="text-center mt-2 mb-4 text-sm font-medium">
                            <input name='files' type="file" id="files" class="hidden" />
                            <label class="bg-green-500 rounded-lg px-4 text-white cursor-pointer shadow-lg hover:bg-green-600 hover:border-green-500 transition duration-300 ease-in-out py-2" for="files">Select Image</label>
                         </div>
                            <button name="submit" class="inline-block px-6 py-2.5 bg-green-600 text-white font-medium text-xs leading-tight uppercase rounded shadow-md hover:bg-green-700 hover:shadow-lg focus:bg-green-700 focus:shadow-lg focus:outline-none focus:ring-0 active:bg-green-800 active:shadow-lg transition duration-150 ease-in-out">
                            UPDATE
                            </button>
                    </div>
                    </form>
```

****Now our PHP Code:****

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        // File name
        //var_dump($_POST['files']); die;
        $filename = $_FILES['files']['name'];
        var_dump($filename);
        var_dump($_FILES);
        // Location
        $target_file = 'upload/' . $filename;
        // file extension
        $file_extension = pathinfo(
            $target_file,
            PATHINFO_EXTENSION
        );
        $file_extension = strtolower($file_extension);
        // Valid image extension
        $valid_extension = array("png", "jpeg", "jpg");
    if (in_array($file_extension, $valid_extension)) {
        // Upload file
        if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][$i], $target_file)) {
            echo "";
        }
    }
            // Upload file
    try {
        if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['files']['tmp_name'], $target_file)) {
                    $query = "INSERT INTO `images` (`vraag_id`, `img_name`, `image`) VALUES (?, ?, ?)";
                    $statement = $conn->prepare($query);
                    $statement->execute(array($id2, $filename, $target_file));
        } else {
            throw new \Exception("Error saving file '$target_file'");
        }
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Files are always going to `$_FILES`. Your input is hidden, so it may just be empty.

Comment: `it is being saved to $_POST Array.`...this doesn't make any sense. Show us the output of `var_dump($_FILES);` and `var_dump($_POST);` after submitting your form with all fields completed.